# How can I show the complex sine function is unbounded?

Tags: complex-analysis

My question is really simple. How can I show intuitively to my complex analysis students that the sine function is unbounded? What kind of behavior makes the complex sine function different from the real one in this sense?

Comment: If you look at the series expansion for example it is visible that, in contrast to the real case, the alternating term disappears if you calculate $\sin(ix)$ for real $x$.

Comment: $\sin(ix) = i\sinh x$

Comment: Liouville's theorem tells us that no functions are bounded in the complex plane, unless they are constants.

Comment: Observe that $e^x$ is unbounded. Now for $ix\in i\Bbb R$ we have that $\sin(x)=\frac{e^{-x}-e^x}{2i}$

Comment: @Kaynex To be exact : A HOLOMORPHIC bounded function must be constant. But this is hardly an intuitive approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $$\sin : z \mapsto \sin(z)$$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}.$ Hence, if it is bounded, it is constant by Liouville's theorem. It is of course a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a picture displaying $|\sin(x+iy)|$ as a function of $x$ and $y$ that may be appealing to students: the $x$ variable conveys the *circular* trigonometry part ($-2 \pi < x < 2 \pi$)  and the $y$ variable ($-1 < y < 1$)  accounts for the *hyperbolic* trigonometry part:

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKKGH.jpg)

Explanation: using Euler formulas: $$\sin(x+iy)=\sin(x)\cosh(y)+i \cos(x)\sinh(y)$$

The square of the modulus of this expression is $$(\cosh(y)\sin(x))^2+(\cos(x)\sinh(y))^2$$

which is arbitrary large: for example, if $x=\pi/2$, it is equal to $$\cosh(y)^2$$

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach you can provide as far as boundedness of sine function is concerned. We know that $$\sin^{2}z + \cos^{2}z = 1\tag{1}$$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ and if $z \in \mathbb{R}$ then $\cos z, \sin z$ are also real and then from the above equation it follows that $\sin z, \cos z$ are bounded.

If $z$ is not real then $\cos z, \sin z$ are not real and hence the equation $(1)$ does not really lead us to the conclusion that $\cos z, \sin z$ are bounded. In fact more generally if $a \in \mathbb{C}$ then $b = \sqrt{1 - a^{2}} \in \mathbb{C}$ no matter how large $|a|$ is. So one thing is clear: if $z \in \mathbb{C} - \mathbb{R}$ then one should not expect that $\sin z, \cos z$ are bounded.

Next one should be able to show that $\sin z, \cos z$ are actually unbounded and this is easily done by noting that $|\sin ix| = \sinh x, |\cos ix| = \cosh x$ for all real $x > 0$ and these tends to $\infty$ as $x \to \infty$.